# HDFS calculate size of subfolders

Tags: size, hdfs

Please advice on how can I calculate the size of subfolders in HDFS and sort them by size?

`hdfs dfs -ls -h /mds/snapshots/user/data | du -sh * | sort -rh | head -10`

Seems it should work - but as I understand `hdfs` doesn't work with additional commands after `|`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
hdfs dfs -du -s /path/* | sort -r -k 1 -g | awk '{ suffix="KMGT"; for(i=0;
$1>1024 && i < length(suffix); i++) $1/=1024; print int($1) substr(suffix, i,
1), $3; }'
```

Comment: It seems that this answer is good for the OP's problem. Could you also try to improve it by adding some explanation for others to understand how it works? It might also give you some extra upvotes. Thanks!